# How to share an image on Whatsapp/Facebook/Instagram and any other social media using cordova?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Im developing an app on cordova and I would like to add a feature that enables the user to share an image on every media possible like email, whatsapp, facebook, twitter, instagram and so on. Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the social sharing phonegap plugin

Some examples:

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, null, 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', null)">image only</button>
// Beware: passing a base64 file as 'data:' is not supported on Android 2.x: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7901#c43
// Hint: when sharing a base64 encoded file on Android you can set the filename by passing it as the subject (second param)
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(null, 'Android filename', 'data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDAAMALMBAP8AAP///wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAUKAAEALAAAAAAMAAwAQAQZMMhJK7iY4p3nlZ8XgmNlnibXdVqolmhcRQA7', null)">base64 image only</button>
// Hint: you can share multiple files by using an array as thirds param: ['file 1','file 2', ..], but beware of this Android Kitkat Facebook issue: [#164]
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message and image', null, 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', null)">message and image</button>
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message, image and link', null, 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 'http://www.x-services.nl')">message, image and link</button>
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message, subject, image and link', 'The subject', 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo4w.png', 'http://www.x-services.nl')">message, subject, image and link</button>
```

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin